# Ajax Integration with Javascript and Struts 1.2

Tags: java

How to set different Bill no for different customer in a jsp page so that when i enter same bill no for both the customer and click on save it will clear that text field and allow me enter another one or it will show  message that the bill no alreday given to a customer?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the way you should do it.

```
Reason : It looks like Bill number is unique id or a primary id for one of your table. 
Solution: Do not allow the user to input the bill no, generate it at the server side by your code or just increment the value of the bill no at database level(e.g auto_increment).

if still you do not want to do it at the database level you can keep a `static field named billNo` anywhere in your code and just increment its value everytime a request is made.
Problems: This method will fail when your application restarts. you will loose this count.
Solution: Get the last saved bill no from database and set it to the field `billNo`
```